# How to get a list number by a name of an item in a dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a list with only dicts in it and I want to get the position of the first occurrence of an string (item) in all of the dicts.

The list in question:

```json
[
    {
        "signature": "abc",
        "type": "list",
        "source": "v2",
        "price": 2
    },
    {
        "signature": "def",
        "type": "buyNow",
        "source": "v2",
        "price": 3
    },
    {
        "signature": "ghi",
        "type": "buyNow",
        "source": "v2",
        "price": 10
    }
]
```

I want to get the position of the first occurrence of `"type": "buyNow"` and later work with the other items in the dict.

Comment: `next(i for i, d in enumerate(the_list_in_question) if d["type"] == "buyNow")`?

Comment: Please try to write  some code and post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by:

```
for i in list_name:
    if i['type'] == 'buyNow':
        #Do whatever you want with the dictionary
        break #Exits the for loop because you only want the first occurrence.
```

You can emit the `break` keyword if you want all the occurrences.

Another way of doing this is:

```
next(index for index, dict in enumerate(list_name) if dict['type'] == 'buyNow'))
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to search in a list

```py
def get_type(type_value):
    return next(elem for elem in you_list if elem["type"] == type_value, None)

get_type("buyNow")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this. moreover, if you want to specifically iterate over A dict key like (type) in your example you can use the conditionals help.

```
for i in dic:
for j in i:
    print(j,list(i.values())[0])
    break



output:
signature abc
signature def
signature ghi
```

Comment: Your code won't give a proper output, you haven't done proper indentation in the for loops.